# Select distinct groups of rows according to average

Tags: algorithm, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have table `t_stats` with column `id (INT)` and column `ratio (DECIMAL(8,4))`.
`id` is unique.

I want to query table `t_stats` in order to select 3 groups with the same `AVG(ratio)` (closest possible).

Can be done using temporary tables, as long as I can run it as a script or stored procedure.

---

EDIT: Here is the concrete example:

INPUT:

```
id    ratio
--    -----
24  0.930000
25  0.390000
26  0.800000
27  0.920000
28  0.550000
30  0.810000
31  0.770000
32  0.800000
33  0.590000
36  0.760000
37  0.910000
40  0.690000
43  0.390000
45  0.310000
46  0.760000
47  0.710000
54  0.710000
55  0.950000
57  0.920000
60  0.890000
62  0.700000
66  0.890000
68  0.950000
107 0.760000
559 0.990000
560 0.540000
565 0.430000
566 0.830000
568 0.590000
579 0.970000
599 0.900000
623 0.450000
749 0.800000
750 0.970000
753 0.820000
754 0.730000
766 0.620000
768 0.430000
770 0.790000
838 0.700000
875 0.835000
987 0.900000
988 0.740000
1157    0.850000
1250    0.630000
1328    0.860000
2171    0.900000
2176    0.520000
2177    0.980000
2178    0.940000
2180    0.970000
2184    0.990000
2187    0.950000
2188    0.940000
2189    0.920000
2195    0.990000
2233    0.900000
2234    0.940000
2235    0.950000
2240    0.980000
2243    0.920000
2253    0.900000
2266    0.530000
2269    0.920000
2270    0.970000
2271    0.750000
2272    0.820000
2275    0.910000
2277    0.930000
2281    0.690000
2282    0.710000
2288    0.840000
2528    0.870000
2778    0.950000
2814    0.990000
```

OUTPUT:

```
groupId    id     ratio
-------    --     -----
1       24      0.930000
1       25      0.390000
1       27      0.920000
1       30      0.810000
1       32      0.800000
1       36      0.760000
1       54      0.710000
1       60      0.890000
1       559     0.990000
1       560     0.540000
1       566     0.830000
1       568     0.590000
1       623     0.450000
1       750     0.970000
1       838     0.700000
1       987     0.900000
1       1157        0.850000
1       2178        0.940000
1       2180        0.970000
1       2253        0.900000
1       2269        0.920000
1       2271        0.750000
1       2281        0.690000
1       2778        0.950000
1       2814        0.990000
2       26      0.800000
2       28      0.550000
2       31      0.770000
2       40      0.690000
2       45      0.310000
2       55      0.950000
2       57      0.920000
2       66      0.890000
2       107     0.760000
2       565     0.430000
2       579     0.970000
2       753     0.820000
2       754     0.730000
2       766     0.620000
2       875     0.835000
2       1328        0.860000
2       2176        0.520000
2       2177        0.980000
2       2184        0.990000
2       2187        0.950000
2       2189        0.920000
2       2233        0.900000
2       2234        0.940000
2       2275        0.910000
2       2282        0.710000
3       33      0.590000
3       37      0.910000
3       43      0.390000
3       46      0.760000
3       47      0.710000
3       62      0.700000
3       68      0.950000
3       599     0.900000
3       749     0.800000
3       768     0.430000
3       770     0.790000
3       988     0.740000
3       1250        0.630000
3       2171        0.900000
3       2188        0.940000
3       2195        0.990000
3       2235        0.950000
3       2240        0.980000
3       2243        0.920000
3       2266        0.530000
3       2270        0.970000
3       2272        0.820000
3       2277        0.930000
3       2288        0.840000
3       2528        0.870000
```

So I want to make 3 groups of `n` values and aim for a specific average value `x`. (Exemple with `n=30` and `0.75 < x < 0.85` would look like 3 groups of 30 values each where each group has `0.75 < AVG(ratio) < 0.85` and an `id` can only belong to 1 group.)

So average is almost same in each group, and close to `x`:

```
groupId     avg(ratio)
-------     ----------
1           0.805600
2           0.789000
3           0.797600
```

Comment: This is like the Travelling Salesman problem.  You would need to compare all combinations and pick the best performer.  And for even moderate sized datasets it's a huge number of combinations!  Unless you're happy to make a naive estimate?  *[Order by size, rows 1-3 go to groups 1-3, then rows 4-6 go to groups 1-3, etc, etc.]*

Comment: At the moment this is what I use. But I was hoping for a less naive solution.

Comment: You need to look at optimisation algorithms.  SQL is not like the best environment.

Comment: @Dems: I added `C#` and `linq-to-sql` to the tags, if that can help provide a more optimized solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a T-SQL procedural version that is somewhat like a [draft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_%28sports%29), only draft order is optimized each round according to need.

The "competitive" nature of this seems to lead to slightly less than perfect ratios if all items are to be picked, but the up-side is that you basically have an O(N^2) algorithm since it's essentially a min function in a loop (maybe that's optimistic considering the `group by` clauses).  It's also deterministic, and should be fairly straightforward to implement in another layer if necessary.

```
-- SET THESE!
declare @numberOfGroups int = 3
declare @itemsPerGroup int = 25
declare @targetRatio decimal(8,4) = .8
-- /SET

set nocount on

-- Create a table of items
declare @t_stats table (
      id int not null primary key
    , ratio decimal(8,4) not null
    , grp int null
)
insert into @t_stats (id, ratio) values
    (24,0.930000), (25,0.390000), (26,0.800000),
    (27,0.920000), (28,0.550000), (30,0.810000),
    (31,0.770000), (32,0.800000), (33,0.590000),
    (36,0.760000), (37,0.910000), (40,0.690000),
    (43,0.390000), (45,0.310000), (46,0.760000),
    (47,0.710000), (54,0.710000), (55,0.950000),
    (57,0.920000), (60,0.890000), (62,0.700000),
    (66,0.890000), (68,0.950000), (107,0.760000),
    (559,0.990000), (560,0.540000), (565,0.430000),
    (566,0.830000), (568,0.590000), (579,0.970000),
    (599,0.900000), (623,0.450000), (749,0.800000),
    (750,0.970000), (753,0.820000), (754,0.730000),
    (766,0.620000), (768,0.430000), (770,0.790000),
    (838,0.700000), (875,0.835000), (987,0.900000),
    (988,0.740000), (1157,0.850000), (1250,0.630000),
    (1328,0.860000), (2171,0.900000), (2176,0.520000),
    (2177,0.980000), (2178,0.940000), (2180,0.970000),
    (2184,0.990000), (2187,0.950000), (2188,0.940000),
    (2189,0.920000), (2195,0.990000), (2233,0.900000),
    (2234,0.940000), (2235,0.950000), (2240,0.980000),
    (2243,0.920000), (2253,0.900000), (2266,0.530000),
    (2269,0.920000), (2270,0.970000), (2271,0.750000),
    (2272,0.820000), (2275,0.910000), (2277,0.930000),
    (2281,0.690000), (2282,0.710000), (2288,0.840000),
    (2528,0.870000), (2778,0.950000), (2814,0.990000)

-- Create a table of groups
declare @groups table (
    grp int not null primary key identity
)
while (select isnull(max(grp), 0) from @groups) < @numberOfGroups begin
    insert into @groups default values
end

-- Check that we have enough items to fill all groups
if @numberOfGroups * @itemsPerGroup <= (select count(*) from @t_stats) begin

    -- Groups now pick the best-fitting items one at a time
    while (select count(*) from @t_stats where grp is not null) < (select count(*) * @itemsPerGroup from @groups) begin
        declare @grp int, @Num int, @ratio decimal(8,4), @id int

        -- Find the group with the least number of items or the worst ratio
        select top 1 @grp = grp, @Num = Num, @ratio = ratio
        from (
            select g.grp
                , count(i.grp) as Num
                , isnull(avg(i.ratio), 0.0) as ratio
                , abs(@targetRatio - avg(i.ratio)) as RatioDist
            from @groups g
                left join @t_stats i on g.grp = i.grp
            group by g.grp
        ) as a
        order by Num, RatioDist, grp

        -- Let that group make their best pick
        select top 1 @id = id
        from (
            select id
                , abs(((ratio + (@ratio * @Num)) / (@Num + 1)) - @targetRatio) as NewRatioDist
            from @t_stats
            where grp is null
        ) as a
        order by NewRatioDist

        -- Update the items table based upon the pick
        update @t_stats set grp = @grp where id = @id

    end

end
else begin
    -- Not enought items
    raiserror('Too many groups or items per group.', 17, 0)
end

-- Display the results
select grp, count(*) as Num, avg(ratio) as ratio
from @t_stats
group by grp
order by grp
```

Comment: Thanks, though there is plenty of room for optimization here.  Please update us if you do anything to make this better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Declare @t Table (Id Int, Ratio DECIMAL(8,2)) 
Insert Into @t Values(1,0.5),(2,0.55),(3,0.97),(4,0.77),(5,0.97),(6,0.99),(7,1.0),(8,0.15),(9,0.33) 

DECLARE @MeanSum DECIMAL(8,2) 
SELECT @MeanSum =SUM(Ratio)/3 FROM @T 

;WITH Cte (Id,Ratio,Ids,RatioValues,RatioTotalWeight,Level) AS 
( 
    SELECT  Id 
            ,Ratio             
            , ',' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(MAX))   
            ,',' + CAST(Ratio AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            ,CAST(Ratio AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
            ,1
    FROM @t 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT          
            p.Id 
            , p.Ratio             
            ,c.Ids + ',' +  CAST(p.Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            ,c.RatioValues + ',' +  CAST(p.Ratio AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
            ,CAST(c.RatioTotalWeight + p.Ratio AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
            ,c.Level+1           
    FROM @t AS p JOIN Cte c ON p.Id < c.Id 
    WHERE c.Level < 3
 ),CTEOf3Groups AS( 
    SELECT  
        Ids = STUFF(Ids,1,1,'') 
        ,RatioValues 
        ,RatioTotalWeight 
        , FirstChar = SUBSTRING(STUFF(Ids,1,1,''),0,CHARINDEX(',',STUFF(Ids,1,1,''))) 
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ABS(RatioTotalWeight - @MeanSum)) [rank] -- gets the closest distance 
    FROM CTE     
),CteGetTheRanks AS( 
Select *, Rn = Row_Number() Over(Partition By FirstChar Order by  FirstChar, [Rank] ) 
From CTEOf3Groups) 
,CteGroups AS( 
SELECT [GroupId] = Row_Number() Over( Order By (Select 1)), Ids,[Rank] 
FROM CteGetTheRanks  
Where [Rank]<=3 
AND Rn = 1) 

SELECT X.[GroupId],X.Id,t.Ratio 
FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT F1.[GroupId],  
         O.splitdata  AS ID 
         FROM 
             ( 
                SELECT *, 
                CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(F.Ids,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS xmlfilter 
                FROM CteGroups F 
             )F1 
         CROSS APPLY 
         (  
            SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') AS splitdata  
            FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') As fdata(D) 
         ) O 
    )X JOIN @t t ON t.Id = X.ID 
ORDER BY 1,2 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Result**
[image]

**Edited**
I tried with the sampel data that you provided (ddl provied for your reference)

```
Declare @t Table (Id Int, Ratio DECIMAL(8,2)) 
Insert Into @t Values
(52,0.930000),(53,0.390000),(54,0.800000),(55,0.920000),(56,0.550000),  
(58,0.810000),(59,0.770000),(60,0.800000),(61,0.590000),(64,0.760000),  
(65,0.910000),(68,0.690000),(71,0.390000),(73,0.310000),(74,0.760000),  
(75,0.710000),(82,0.710000),(83,0.950000),(85,0.920000),(88,0.890000),  
(90,0.700000),(94,0.890000),(96,0.950000),(135,0.760000),(587,0.990000),  
(588,0.540000),(593,0.430000),(594,0.830000),(596,0.590000),(607,0.970000),  
(627,0.900000),(651,0.450000),(777,0.800000),(778,0.970000),(781,0.820000),  
(782,0.730000),(794,0.620000),(796,0.430000),(798,0.790000),(866,0.700000),  
(903,0.835000),(1015,0.900000),(1016,0.740000),(1185,0.850000),(1278,0.630000),  
(1356,0.860000),(2199,0.900000),(2204,0.520000),(2205,0.980000),(2206,0.940000),  
(2208,0.970000),(2212,0.990000),(2215,0.950000),(2216,0.940000),(2217,0.920000),  
(2223,0.990000),(2261,0.900000),(2262,0.940000),(2263,0.950000),(2268,0.980000),  
(2271,0.920000),(2281,0.900000),(2294,0.530000),(2297,0.920000),(2298,0.970000),  
(2299,0.750000),(2300,0.820000),(2303,0.910000),(2305,0.930000),(2309,0.690000),  
(2310,0.710000),(2316,0.840000),(2556,0.870000),(2806,0.950000),(2842,0.990000),  
(2844,0.710000),(2977,0.730000),(2985,0.960000),(3008,0.710000),(3042,0.910000),  
(3061,0.830000),(3243,0.900000),(3346,0.800000),(3371,0.800000),(3497,0.990000),  
(3838,0.730000),(4000,0.980000),(4001,0.890000),(4002,0.850000),(4003,0.490000),  
(4004,0.970000),(4009,0.930000),(4032,0.930000),(4095,0.460000),(4428,0.610000),  
(4438,0.960000),(4439,0.930000),(4445,0.650000),(4446,0.660000),(4447,0.490000),  
(4455,0.880000),(4457,0.890000),(4460,0.980000),(4469,0.930000),(4473,0.980000),  
(4474,0.950000),(4475,0.940000),(4481,0.400000),(4489,0.760000),(4490,0.470000)
```

And the result is

[image]

The time taken for execution is 27 secs. Please test from your end (also the result) and let me know.

**Edited**

75 record DDL

```
Declare @t Table (Id Int, Ratio DECIMAL(8,4))  
Insert Into @t Values 
(24,0.930000),(25,0.390000),(26,0.800000),(27,0.920000),
(28,0.550000),(30,0.810000),(31,0.770000),(32,0.800000),
(33,0.590000),(36,0.760000),(37,0.910000),(40,0.690000),
(43,0.390000),(45,0.310000),(46,0.760000),(47,0.710000),
(54,0.710000),(55,0.950000),(57,0.920000),(60,0.890000),
(62,0.700000),(66,0.890000),(68,0.950000),(107,0.760000),
(559,0.990000),(560,0.540000),(565,0.430000),(566,0.830000),
(568,0.590000),(579,0.970000),(599,0.900000),(623,0.450000),
(749,0.800000),(750,0.970000),(753,0.820000),(754,0.730000),
(766,0.620000),(768,0.430000),(770,0.790000),(838,0.700000),
(875,0.835000),(987,0.900000),(988,0.740000),(1157,0.850000),
(1250,0.630000),(1328,0.860000),(2171,0.900000),(2176,0.520000),
(2177,0.980000),(2178,0.940000),(2180,0.970000),(2184,0.990000),
(2187,0.950000),(2188,0.940000),(2189,0.920000),(2195,0.990000),
(2233,0.900000),(2234,0.940000),(2235,0.950000),(2240,0.980000),
(2243,0.920000),(2253,0.900000),(2266,0.530000),(2269,0.920000),
(2270,0.970000),(2271,0.750000),(2272,0.820000),(2275,0.910000),
(2277,0.930000),(2281,0.690000),(2282,0.710000),(2288,0.840000),
(2528,0.870000),(2778,0.950000),(2814,0.990000)
```

Comment: I can't test your solution with my Data (110 rows instead of 9 is too many rows for the WITH clause...). `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: I would love to try it and see the results, but with a 75 row table it's been running for 20 minutes, and still running. Maybe someone could optimise your solution?

Comment: Could you please give me the data with the respected output.I will optimize my solution and will get back to you.1 tips though... instead store the result in some intermediate temp table with index created and try that out.

Comment: @Francis P, modified the query

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear in my explanation, but you misunderstood the requirements. 1st: I need 3 Groups of n elements, not n groups of 3 elements. 2nd: element can't be in 2 groups.

Comment: can you please provide a small sample input data with the output you are expecting. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

SQL really isn't the best tool for this sort of problem.

However, sometimes it's fun to bash some screws with the TSQL hammer!!

Here's an effort that gets the following on your 75 row example data:

```
  GroupId     Average                                 Count
  ----------- --------------------------------------- -----------
  1           0.798400                                25
  2           0.796600                                25
  3           0.797200                                25
```

In under a second on my machine.
Just one caveat: This method has massive flaws but if you need to do this in SQL you can probably gaffer tape over them a bit, I just didn't have time to.

```
-- **Expects data in table t_stats (id, ratio)**
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') is not null drop table #data
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pairsets') is not null drop table #pairsets
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pairseed') is not null drop table #pairseed
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#match') is not null drop proc #match
go

-- rather horrible routine using dsql to find either:
--   1) groups of values that sum to exactly @targetsum (only if @targetsum non null)
--   2) the group containing the least values that includes data id @includeid and where the sum is within +- @targetsumrange
create proc #match(@targetsum DECIMAL(8,4), @includeid int, @targetsumrange DECIMAL(8,4)) as
begin
  set nocount on
  declare @nearestmatch bit = 0
  if @targetsum is null set @nearestmatch = 1
  declare @combination table (value int, asstring varchar(10), alias varchar(50))  
  declare @savedpairseed int = (select pairseed from #pairseed)

  declare @stmtTemplate varchar(max) = 'declare @pairseed int = (select pairseed from #pairseed)
  declare @DistSum DECIMAL(8,4)
  <DeclareVars>
  declare candloop cursor for select <SelectList>, <DistanceSum> as Dist_sum from <TableList> where <IdCheck> <SumCheck>
  open candloop
  fetch next from candloop into <VarsList>, @DistSum
  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
    if (select count(*) from #data where id in (<VarsList>)) = <VarsCount>
    begin
      <DeleteData>
      <InsertPairs>
      set @pairseed = @pairseed + 1  
    end
    fetch next from candloop into <VarsList>, @DistSum
  end
  close candloop
  deallocate candloop
  update #pairseed set pairseed = @pairseed  '

  declare @combinations int = 1
  declare @maxcombinations int = 8
  while @combinations <= @maxcombinations
  begin
    insert @combination select @combinations, cast(@combinations as varchar(10)), char(ascii('a') + @combinations-1)
    declare @DeclareVars varchar(max) = ''
    declare @SelectList varchar(max) = ''
    declare @TableList varchar(max) = ''
    declare @IdCheck varchar(max) = ''
    declare @DistanceSum varchar(max) = ''
    declare @InsertPairs varchar(max) = ''
    declare @VarsList varchar(max) = ''
    declare @SumCheck varchar(max) = ''
    declare @DeleteData varchar(max) = 'delete #data where id in (<VarsList>)'

    select @DeclareVars = @DeclareVars + 'declare @id'+asstring+ ' int ' from @combination
    select @SelectList = @SelectList + alias +'.id, ' from @combination
    set @SelectList = SUBSTRING(@selectlist, 1, LEN(@SelectList)-1)
    select @TableList = @TableList + '#data '+alias+', ' from @combination
    set @TableList = SUBSTRING(@TableList, 1, LEN(@TableList)-1)
    select @IdCheck = @IdCheck + a.alias+'.id < '+b.alias+'.id and '
    from @combination a join @combination b on a.value+1 = b.value   
    if LEN(@IdCheck) > 4
      set @IdCheck = SUBSTRING(@IdCheck, 1, LEN(@IdCheck)-4) + ' and '
    select @DistanceSum = @DistanceSum + alias+'.targetdistance + ' from @combination
    set @DistanceSum = SUBSTRING(@DistanceSum, 1, LEN(@DistanceSum)-2)
    select @VarsList = @VarsList + '@id'+asstring+ ', ' from @combination
    set @VarsList = SUBSTRING(@VarsList, 1, LEN(@VarsList)-1)
    select @InsertPairs = @InsertPairs + 'insert #pairsets select @pairseed, @id'+asstring+ ', @DistSum'+ CHAR(10) from @combination
    set @SumCheck = @DistanceSum + ' = '+ cast(@Targetsum as varchar(20))   

    if @nearestmatch = 1 
    begin
      set @SumCheck = '('
      select @SumCheck = @SumCheck + alias+'.id = '+CAST(@includeid as varchar(10))+' or ' from @combination
      if LEN(@SumCheck) > 4
        set @SumCheck = SUBSTRING(@SumCheck, 1, LEN(@SumCheck)-3)
      set @SumCheck = @SumCheck + ')'
      set @DeleteData = ''
    end

    declare @stmt varchar(max)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmtTemplate, '<DeclareVars>', @DeclareVars)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<DeleteData>', @DeleteData)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<SelectList>', @SelectList)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<TableList>', @TableList)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<IdCheck>', @IdCheck)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<DistanceSum>', @DistanceSum)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<InsertPairs>', @InsertPairs)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<VarsList>', @VarsList)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<VarsCount>', cast(@combinations as varchar(10)))
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<SumCheck>', @SumCheck)       
    exec (@stmt)    
    set @combinations = @combinations + 1
  end

  if @nearestmatch = 1
  begin
    -- above will have recorded all possible matches within range
    -- remove all but the closest and reindex the pair ids
    declare @bestmatch int
    select top 1 @bestmatch = pairid from #pairsets where pairid >= @savedpairseed and ABS(distsum) < @targetsumrange 
    delete #pairsets where pairid >= @savedpairseed and pairid <> ISNULL(@bestmatch, -1)
    delete #data where id in (select id from #pairsets where pairid = @bestmatch)
    update #pairsets set pairid = @savedpairseed where pairid = @bestmatch
    update #pairseed set pairseed = @savedpairseed+1
  end

end

go
set nocount on
-- set the parameters
declare @xmin DECIMAL(8,4) = 0.75
declare @xmax DECIMAL(8,4) = 0.85
declare @xrange DECIMAL(8,4) = @xmax - @xmin
declare @xtarg DECIMAL(8,4) = (@xmin+@xmax) / 2
declare @ngroups int = 3
declare @targetgroupsize int = 25

declare @maxbalancedpair int 

-- copy the ratio data (using 75 row data from updated question)
select *, ratio-@xtarg as targetdistance, abs(ratio - @xtarg) as targetdistanceabsolute into #data from t_stats
create table #pairseed (pairseed int)
create table #pairsets (pairid int, id int, distsum DECIMAL(8,4) )
insert #pairseed select 1

-- due to the 2 decimal points and distribution of the data we can find many n-tuples that sum to zero
exec #match 0, 0, 0

select @maxbalancedpair = pairseed-1 from #pairseed

declare @deviants table (id int)
declare @most_deviant int
while exists(select * from #data where id not in (select id from @deviants)) 
begin
  select top 1 @most_deviant = id from #data where id not in (select id from @deviants)  order by targetdistanceabsolute desc
  insert @deviants select @most_deviant
  exec #match null, @most_deviant, @xrange
end

-- in general there would have to be some backtracking here
-- now its a box-packing problem, but for simplicity just assign them round robin
declare  @output_group_pairs table (groupid int, pairid int)
declare @groupidx int = 1
declare @numgroups int = 3
declare @pairid int
select @pairid = pairseed-1 from #pairseed

while @pairid >= 0
begin
  insert @output_group_pairs select @groupidx, @pairid
  set @pairid = @pairid - 1
  set @groupidx = (@groupidx % @numgroups) + 1
end

-- wimpy effort at redistributing the groups evenly
-- todo: many cases will not work, should use a proper algorithm

declare @maxiter int = 100
declare @previouspairs table (pairid int)
declare @previousgroups table (groupid int)
while exists(select groupid from @output_group_pairs a join #pairsets b on a.pairid = b.pairid group by groupid having COUNT(id) < @targetgroupsize)
begin  
  set @maxiter = @maxiter-1
  if @maxiter = 0 break
  declare @groupid int = -1
  declare @amountout int
  select @groupid = groupid, @amountout = @targetgroupsize-COUNT(*) 
  from @output_group_pairs a join #pairsets b on a.pairid = b.pairid 
  where groupid not in (select groupid from @previousgroups)
  group by groupid having COUNT(*) < @targetgroupsize
  if @groupid = -1 break

  declare @targetpair int = -1  

  select @targetpair = a.pairid from @output_group_pairs a
  join (select pairid from #pairsets group by pairid having COUNT(*) <= @amountout) b on a.pairid = b.pairid
  join (select groupid, count(id) groupcount from @output_group_pairs a join #pairsets b on a.pairid = b.pairid group by groupid) group_counts on a.groupid = group_counts.groupid
  where a.pairid not in (select pairid from @previouspairs)
  order by abs(@amountout - groupcount) asc

  if @targetpair = -1
  begin
    insert @previousgroups select @groupid
  end
  else
  begin
    insert @previouspairs select @targetpair
    update @output_group_pairs set groupid = @groupid where pairid = @targetpair   
  end
end

set @maxiter = 100
delete @previouspairs
delete @previousgroups
while exists(select groupid from @output_group_pairs a join #pairsets b on a.pairid = b.pairid group by groupid having COUNT(id) > @targetgroupsize)
begin  
  set @maxiter = @maxiter-1
  if @maxiter = 0 break
  set @groupid = -1
  set @amountout = null
  select @groupid = groupid, @amountout = COUNT(*)-@targetgroupsize 
  from @output_group_pairs a join #pairsets b on a.pairid = b.pairid 
  where groupid not in (select groupid from @previousgroups)
  group by groupid having COUNT(*) > @targetgroupsize
  if @groupid = -1 break

  set @targetpair = -1 

  select @targetpair = a.pairid from @output_group_pairs a
  join (select pairid from #pairsets group by pairid having COUNT(*) <= @amountout) b on a.pairid = b.pairid
  join (select groupid, count(id) groupcount from @output_group_pairs a join #pairsets b on a.pairid = b.pairid group by groupid) group_counts on a.groupid = group_counts.groupid
  where a.pairid not in (select pairid from @previouspairs)
  order by abs(@amountout - groupcount) asc

  if @targetpair = -1
  begin
    insert @previousgroups select @groupid
  end
  else
  begin  
    insert @previouspairs select @targetpair
    delete @output_group_pairs where pairid = @targetpair
  end   
end

-- output groups and their stats
select GroupId, Id from @output_group_pairs a join #pairsets b on a.pairid = b.pairid order by 1, 2

select a.GroupId, AVG(c.ratio) as [Average] , count(*) as [Count]
from @output_group_pairs a
join #pairsets b on a.pairid = b.pairid
join t_stats c on b.id = c.id
group by a.groupid
go

drop table #data
drop table #pairsets
drop table #pairseed
drop proc #match
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I'm impressed! How can I alter your script in order to specify how many items per group I want? (make 3 groups of 20 values from the 75 values in `t_stats`)

Comment: Another thing: you've set `@xmin=0.75` and `@xmax=0.85`, which gives groups having `AVG(ratio)` around 0.79 and `COUNT(*)=25` (Perfect). If I change those values to `@xmin=0.78` and `@xmax=0.80`, I then get `AVG(ratio)=0.90` and `COUNT(*)=9672` (That's a problem).

Comment: Oh.. your example was to get 3 groups of 30 out of 75 so I ignored the requirement for that "n" to be variable but it could be added to the box packing part fairly easily (this is probably the part with the biggest problems as it stands). The bug that affects the 0.78 to 0.80 case is in lines 131 to 137, comment them out and it refrains from adding ids to multiple groups.

Comment: So can you help adapting the box packing part to select "n" elements?

Comment: I've updated the code to make a simple "greedy" attempt to get the groups to the target size.

Answer (score 0):

Oh and if the number of items in a group is a precise requirement, here's a version that uses the same exhaustive match for the box-packing part, its much slower though.

```
-- **Expects data in table t_stats (id, ratio)**
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data') is not null drop table #data
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#data_pairs') is not null drop table #data_pairs
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pairsets') is not null drop table #pairsets
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#pairseed') is not null drop table #pairseed
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#match') is not null drop proc #match
go

-- rather horrible routine using dsql to find either:
--   1) groups of values that sum to exactly @targetsum (only if @targetsum non null)
--   2) the group containing the least values that includes data id @includeid and where the sum is within +- @targetsumrange
create proc #match(@targetsum DECIMAL(8,4), @maxcombinations int, @includeid int, @targetsumrange DECIMAL(8,4)) as
begin
  set nocount on
  declare @nearestmatch bit = 0
  if @targetsum is null set @nearestmatch = 1
  declare @combination table (value int, asstring varchar(10), alias varchar(50))  
  declare @savedpairseed int = (select pairseed from #pairseed)

  declare @stmtTemplate varchar(max) = 'declare @pairseed int = (select pairseed from #pairseed)
  declare @DistSum DECIMAL(8,4)
  <DeclareVars>
  declare candloop cursor for select <SelectList>, <DistanceSum> as Dist_sum from <TableList> where <IdCheck> <SumCheck>
  open candloop
  fetch next from candloop into <VarsList>, @DistSum
  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
    if (select count(*) from #data where id in (<VarsList>)) = <VarsCount>
    begin
      <DeleteData>
      <InsertPairs>
      set @pairseed = @pairseed + 1  
    end
    fetch next from candloop into <VarsList>, @DistSum
  end
  close candloop
  deallocate candloop
  update #pairseed set pairseed = @pairseed  '

  declare @combinations int = 1
  while @combinations <= @maxcombinations
  begin
    insert @combination 
    select @combinations, cast(@combinations as varchar(10)), CHAR(ASCII('a')+ (@combinations-1)%26) + char(ascii('a') + @combinations-1)
    declare @DeclareVars varchar(max) = ''
    declare @SelectList varchar(max) = ''
    declare @TableList varchar(max) = ''
    declare @IdCheck varchar(max) = ''
    declare @DistanceSum varchar(max) = ''
    declare @InsertPairs varchar(max) = ''
    declare @VarsList varchar(max) = ''
    declare @SumCheck varchar(max) = ''
    declare @DeleteData varchar(max) = 'delete #data where id in (<VarsList>)'

    select @DeclareVars = @DeclareVars + 'declare @id'+asstring+ ' int ' from @combination
    select @SelectList = @SelectList + alias +'.id, ' from @combination
    set @SelectList = SUBSTRING(@selectlist, 1, LEN(@SelectList)-1)
    select @TableList = @TableList + '#data '+alias+', ' from @combination
    set @TableList = SUBSTRING(@TableList, 1, LEN(@TableList)-1)
    select @IdCheck = @IdCheck + a.alias+'.id < '+b.alias+'.id and '
    from @combination a join @combination b on a.value+1 = b.value   
    if LEN(@IdCheck) > 4
      set @IdCheck = SUBSTRING(@IdCheck, 1, LEN(@IdCheck)-4) + ' and '
    select @DistanceSum = @DistanceSum + alias+'.targetdistance + ' from @combination
    set @DistanceSum = SUBSTRING(@DistanceSum, 1, LEN(@DistanceSum)-2)
    select @VarsList = @VarsList + '@id'+asstring+ ', ' from @combination
    set @VarsList = SUBSTRING(@VarsList, 1, LEN(@VarsList)-1)
    select @InsertPairs = @InsertPairs + 'insert #pairsets select @pairseed, @id'+asstring+ ', @DistSum'+ CHAR(10) from @combination
    set @SumCheck = @DistanceSum + ' = '+ cast(@Targetsum as varchar(20))   

    if @nearestmatch = 1 
    begin
      set @SumCheck = '('
      select @SumCheck = @SumCheck + alias+'.id = '+CAST(@includeid as varchar(10))+' or ' from @combination
      if LEN(@SumCheck) > 4
        set @SumCheck = SUBSTRING(@SumCheck, 1, LEN(@SumCheck)-3)
      set @SumCheck = @SumCheck + ')'
      set @DeleteData = ''
    end

    declare @stmt varchar(max)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmtTemplate, '<DeclareVars>', @DeclareVars)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<DeleteData>', @DeleteData)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<SelectList>', @SelectList)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<TableList>', @TableList)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<IdCheck>', @IdCheck)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<DistanceSum>', @DistanceSum)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<InsertPairs>', @InsertPairs)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<VarsList>', @VarsList)
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<VarsCount>', cast(@combinations as varchar(10)))
    set @stmt = REPLACE(@stmt, '<SumCheck>', @SumCheck) 

    exec (@stmt)    
    set @combinations = @combinations + 1
  end

  if @nearestmatch = 1
  begin
    -- above will have recorded all possible matches within range
    -- remove all but the closest and reindex the pair ids
    declare @bestmatch int
    select top 1 @bestmatch = pairid from #pairsets where pairid >= @savedpairseed and ABS(distsum) < @targetsumrange 
    delete #pairsets where pairid >= @savedpairseed and pairid <> ISNULL(@bestmatch, -1)
    delete #data where id in (select id from #pairsets where pairid = @bestmatch)
    update #pairsets set pairid = @savedpairseed where pairid = @bestmatch
    update #pairseed set pairseed = @savedpairseed+1
  end

end

go
set nocount on
-- set the parameters
declare @xmin DECIMAL(8,4) = 0.75
declare @xmax DECIMAL(8,4) = 0.85
declare @xrange DECIMAL(8,4) = @xmax - @xmin
declare @xtarg DECIMAL(8,4) = (@xmin+@xmax) / 2
declare @ngroups int = 3
declare @targetgroupsize int = 5

declare @maxbalancedpair int 

-- copy the ratio data (using 75 row data from updated question)
select *, ratio-@xtarg as targetdistance, abs(ratio - @xtarg) as targetdistanceabsolute into #data from t_stats
create table #pairseed (pairseed int)
create table #pairsets (pairid int, id int, distsum DECIMAL(8,4) )
insert #pairseed select 1

-- due to the 2 decimal points and distribution of the data we can find many n-tuples that sum to zero
exec #match 0, 8, 0, 0

select @maxbalancedpair = pairseed-1 from #pairseed

declare @deviants table (id int)
declare @most_deviant int
while exists(select * from #data where id not in (select id from @deviants)) 
begin
  select top 1 @most_deviant = id from #data where id not in (select id from @deviants)  order by targetdistanceabsolute desc
  insert @deviants select @most_deviant
  exec #match null, 8, @most_deviant, @xrange
end

select * into #data_pairs from #pairsets
delete #data
delete #pairsets
update #pairseed set pairseed = 1
insert #data
select pairid, COUNT(*), COUNT(*), COUNT(*) from #data_pairs group by pairid

if (select SUM(ratio) from #data) < @targetgroupsize * @ngroups
begin
  raiserror('Cannot match - not enough data', 16, 1)
  return
end

-- find the minimum number of matches that will reach targetgroupsize
declare @maxmatches int = -1
declare @matchcount int
declare @matchsum int = 0
declare maxmatchcount cursor for select CAST(ratio as int) from #data order by ratio asc
open maxmatchcount
fetch next from maxmatchcount into @matchcount
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 and @matchsum <= @targetgroupsize
begin
  set @maxmatches = @maxmatches + 1
  set @matchsum = @matchsum + @matchcount
  fetch next from maxmatchcount into @matchcount
end
close maxmatchcount
deallocate maxmatchcount

exec #match @targetgroupsize, @maxmatches, null, null

declare  @output_group_pairs table (groupid int, pairid int)

insert @output_group_pairs select pairid, id from #pairsets where pairid <= @ngroups

-- output groups and their stats
select GroupId, Id from @output_group_pairs a join #data_pairs b on a.pairid = b.pairid order by 1, 2

select a.GroupId, AVG(c.ratio) as [Average] , count(*) as [Count]
from @output_group_pairs a
join #data_pairs b on a.pairid = b.pairid
join t_stats c on b.id = c.id
group by a.groupid

go

drop table #data
drop table #data_pairs
drop table #pairsets
drop table #pairseed
drop proc #match
```

Comment: I wonder how your code works...I'm running it for 3 groups of 25 with `0.75<x<0.85` and it works with final `AVG(ratio)=0.79`. But if I change it for 3 groups of 25 elements, but `0.7<x<0.8` it's not able to find a solution. Why's that?

Comment: In the worst case it will take a lot of memory due to brute forcing the combinations. Maybe you should run all the suggested algortithms and pick the best answer after X seconds... :)